# Exibir todo texto no botão

Tags: html, css, ionic, angular, ionic3

Olá! É possível exibir todo texto do botão nele?

[image: segment button]

Automaticamente está adicionando essas reticências, mas gostaria de exibir todo o texto.

```
      <ion-segment-button  value="Bareserestaurantes" class="round-button" (click)="selecionaprodutoscategoria(2)">
        Bares & Restaurantes
      </ion-segment-button>
```

Comment: A imagem não está carregando, mas acho que da pra entender o que é. Só esta mostrando Bares&Re...

Answer (score 0):

Una solução é alterar o css para permitir a quebra de linha.

```
.round-button{
    white-space: normal;
}
```